# How do I restrict drag events to a container div in Javascript (React)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, dom-events

The div element created by the code below contains a border. If I drag the thumbnail by the border, the drag event's target (ev.target) is the div element. If I drag the thumbnail by the enclosed image, the target is the image itself.

I would like the drag event's target to always be the containing div. I'm trying to do this so I can change the images enclosed in the thumbnail.

```
function Photo_Thumbnail(props){
    return (
        <div draggable="true" onDragStart={dragStart} onDragOver={dragover_handler} onDrop={drop_handler}>
            <Thumbnail src={props.photo}/>
        </div>  
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself.

In the drag event handler, use the event.currentTarget attribute instead of event.target. This will capture the dom element to which the drag event has been bound.